# Can't find defaultTimeLocale in Data.Time.Format

Tags: haskell, cabal

According to the [doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5/docs/Data-Time-Format.html) on Hackage, `Data.Time.Format` exposed `defaultTimeLocal`.
However, when I try to use it, it doesn't exits.

When I look at the code, it doesn't seems to be exposed either (if I generate the doc from the source, I don't see this `defaultTimeLocale`). Is it because it needs to be compiled with some flags, or is the haddock on hackage just wrong.

Where can I get an instance for `TimeLocale`?

## Update

I'm using `time` version 1.5.0.1 on OSX.
The following code

```
import Data.Time.Format (defaultTimeLocale)
```

errors with

```
Module ‘Data.Time.Format’ does not export ‘defaultTimeLocale’
```

## Update

In fact I was using version 1.4.2 which doesn't have `defaultTimeLocale` installed.
I'm upgrading to 1.5.0.1 ...

## Update

I deleted my sandbox, rebuild everything. It's workin now.

Comment: you have `time` installed? (which version?) - also can you please add a simple sample code and at least the beginning of the error message? - for me `import Data.Time.Format` and then `defaultTimeLocale` (mind the **e** at the end) works just fine - *also* what OS are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, cabal wasn't using the version I thought it was (1.5) but (1.4) probably from the haskell platform. Uprading fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this answer who wants to write their library with backwards compatible `time` dependencies, you can use the CPP pragma and an `#if` to check the minimum version of the time library:

```
{-# Language CPP #-}
#if MIN_VERSION_time(1,5,0)
import Data.Time.Format (defaultTimeLocale)
#else
import System.Locale (defaultTimeLocale)
#endif
```